# How do I erase the save data on Elite Beat Agents for the Nintendo DS?

Tags: elite-beat-agents

I purchased Elite Beat Agents used, and there's no apparent way to delete the data that's saved on the game from the previous owner.

Is there a way to reset the game?

Comment: What game is it?

Comment: Just blow on the pins sharply.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's in the manual on page 11 but just in case you didn't get a manual with your used game :

1. Launch the game wait for the screen
   with red Nintendo letters on a black
   screen.
2. Then press AND hold the L,
   R, A, B, X, and Y buttons all at the
   same time.
3. This will give you the
   option to erase the saved data.

Answer (score 2):

Some games provide a button combination pressed on the main menu or title screen that allows you to erase all save data. It is usually in the instruction manual, or you could look it up.

*(Usually, a soft reset refers to a way to power off and on the game console easier than sliding / pressing the power button.)*

Comment: All games are different, yet all the ones i've come across definitely have a way of doing it, so as Mew2468 says you're better off looking for the manual or through the menus, or post up which game you have specifically.

Comment: I updated the question to name the game.  I had wrongfully assumed it was the same button combination for all games, so I made the question more general.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little confusing how there isn't a universal way to erase save data. And I think you mean more specific. :)

Comment: @Kevin While there's not a universal way, are there any ways used commonly enough that they're worth trying on games we're not sure of the method for?

Comment: @Fambida: The method answered by MarmouCorp (A+B+X+Y+L+R during startup) is common.